# Grunt serve delete bower_components/angular-i18n from index.html

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

When I run **grunt serve** it delete this row from index.html

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_it-it.js"></script>
```

My bower.json is:

```
    {
  "name": "operatore-smart",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.13.1",
    "ngToast": "ngtoast#^2.0.0",
    "angularjs-dropdown-multiselect": "^1.5.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "angular-ui-date": "^1.0.1",
    "angular-momentjs": "^0.2.2",
    "angular-i18n": "^1.5.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "operatoreSmartApp",
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
      "main": [
        "less/bootstrap.less",
        "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I also make bower install and the directory bower_components\angular-i18n is correctly installed.

Can you help me?

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!--<base href="/~opw2er34mart/">-->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Titolo</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->
  <!-- build:css(.) styles/vendor.css -->
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ngToast/dist/ngToast.css"/>
  <!-- endbower -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
  <!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/myCss.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="island/css/island.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="user/css/user.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="dashboard/css/authentication.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar/css/calendar.css">
  <!-- endbuild -->
</head>
<body ng-app="SmartApp">
<toast></toast>
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade
  your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
<![endif]-->

<div data-ng-include="'UI/navigation.template.html'"></div>

<!-- Add your site or application content here -->

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12" ui-view></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="footer-style" data-ng-include="'UI/footer.template.html'"></div>


<!-- Google Analytics: change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID -->
<!--<script>-->
<!--!function (A, n, g, u, l, a, r) {-->
<!--A.GoogleAnalyticsObject = l, A[l] = A[l] || function () {-->
<!--(A[l].q = A[l].q || []).push(arguments)-->
<!--}, A[l].l = +new Date, a = n.createElement(g),-->
<!--r = n.getElementsByTagName(g)[0], a.src = u, r.parentNode.insertBefore(a, r)-->
<!--}(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');-->

<!--ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-X');-->
<!--ga('send', 'pageview');-->
<!--</script>-->

<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/lodash/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/ngToast/dist/ngToast.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/src/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-ui-date/dist/date.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-momentjs/angular-momentjs.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_it-it.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script>
  _.contains = _.includes;
</script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="app.routes.js"></script>
<script src="dashboard/controllers/dashboard.controller.js"></script>
<script src="authentication/services/authentication.service.js"></script>
<script src="authentication/controllers/login.controllers.js"></script>
<script src="profile/controllers/profile.controller.js"></script>
<script src="profile/services/user-profile.service.js"></script>
<script src="profile/controllers/notifica.controller.js"></script>
<script src="profile/services/notifica.service.js"></script>
<script src="changepsw/controllers/changepsw.controller.js"></script>
<script src="changepsw/services/change-psw.service.js"></script>
<script src="alarm/controllers/alarm.controller.js"></script>
<script src="alarm/services/alarm.service.js"></script>

<script src="alarm/controllers/alarm.avvisi.controller.js"></script>
<script src="alarm/services/alarm.avvisi.service.js"></script>

<script src="island/controllers/island.controller.js"></script>
<script src="island/controllers/island.groups.controller.js"></script>
<script src="island/services/island.groups.service.js"></script>

<script src="island/services/island.service.js"></script>

<script src="island/controllers/island.accessories.controller.js"></script>
<script src="island/services/island.accessories.service.js"></script>

<script src="island/controllers/island.availabilities.controller.js"></script>
<script src="island/services/island.availabilities.service.js"></script>

<!-- USER COMPONENTS-->
<script src="user/services/user.service.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/user.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/user-modal.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/general-info.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/job.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/documents.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/other-info.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/courses.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/vaccinations.controller.js"></script>
<script src="user/controllers/holidays.controller.js"></script>


<script src="calendar/controllers/calendar.controllers.js"></script>
<script src="calendar/services/calendar.service.js"></script>
<script src="utils/directives/my-checkbox.directive.js"></script>
<script src="calendar/controllers/island-calendar.controller.js"></script>
<script src="calendar/controllers/giustificativi.controller.js"></script>
<script src="utils/directives/select-option.directive.js"></script>
<script src="calendar/services/giustificativi.service.js"></script>

<!-- endbuild -->
</body>
</html>
```

Gruntfile.js

```
    // Generated on 2016-06-24 using generator-angular 0.15.1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Automatically load required Grunt tasks
  require('jit-grunt')(grunt, {
    useminPrepare: 'grunt-usemin',
    ngtemplates: 'grunt-angular-templates',
    cdnify: 'grunt-google-cdn'
  });

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all', 'newer:jscs:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jscs:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'postcss']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect().use(
                '/app/styles',
                connect.static('./app/styles')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par
    jscs: {
      options: {
        config: '.jscsrc',
        verbose: true
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/**/*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git{,*/}*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    postcss: {
      options: {
        processors: [
          require('autoprefixer-core')({browsers: ['last 1 version']})
        ]
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          map: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      },
      test: {
        devDependencies: true,
        src: '<%= karma.unit.configFile %>',
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//,
        fileTypes:{
          js: {
            block: /(([\s\t]*)\/{2}\s*?bower:\s*?(\S*))(\n|\r|.)*?(\/{2}\s*endbower)/gi,
            detect: {
              js: /'(.*\.js)'/gi
            },
            replace: {
              js: '\'{{filePath}}\','
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.css'],
      js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles'
        ],
        patterns: {
          js: [[/(images\/[^''""]*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg))/g, 'Replacing references to images']]
        }
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeComments: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: '**/*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    ngtemplates: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          module: 'operatoreSmartApp',
          htmlmin: '<%= htmlmin.dist.options %>',
          usemin: 'application/application.js'
        },
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
        src: '**/*.html',
        dest: '.tmp/templateCache.js'
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '**/*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: 'bower_components/bootstrap/dist',
          src: 'fonts/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'postcss:server',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'wiredep',
    'concurrent:test',
    'postcss',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'postcss',
    'ngtemplates',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'newer:jscs',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: Since we have no idea of what your gruntfile does, and of the rest of the index.html file is, we can't help.

Comment: The index.html only have link of bower_components and my scripts in angular. The gruntfile.js is generated using generator-angular 0.15.1. I have the problem only with this component :(

Comment: If you want help, you need to collaborate. Put yourself in our shoes, and ask yourself how you could answer your own question. It basically reads as "I have some shell script and it deletes a file. Can you help me?". Then when asked "what does the shell script contain?", you answer "only some instructions". Post the relevant code: your gruntfile, and your index.html. We're not extra-lucid wizards.

Comment: Sorry, here is my file: http://www.filedropper.com/index_39 and http://www.filedropper.com/gruntfile

Comment: The code of the files must be **in the question itself**.

Comment: Ok, I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build uses wiredep to replace everything between

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
```

and

```
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

by a single script loading `scripts/vendor.js` generated by the build and containing all the main js files found in the bower components. So you need to add your additional file outside of these comments, or to add your angular-locale_it-it.js to the main files of the angular-i18n dependency, ad explained in the [wiredep documentation](https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep#bower-overrides).

Comment: Thank you, I have followed your second suggestion doing overrides

Comment: To clarify: Add the i18n locale file between `<!-- endbower -->` and 
`<!-- endbuild -->`